# Dropdown hover menu not showing up in IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, microsoft-edge

I'm using the theme Illdy on a Wordpress site handed to me, and the hoverable dropdown menus on the top navbar are not dropping down in IE or Edge. Firefox and Chrome appear to work. 
I've tried adding a variety of these to the additional CSS:

```
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
visibility: visible;
}
```

```
.header-navigation .menu > li:hover > ul {
opacity: 1;
transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
visibility: visible;
}
.header-navigation .menu-item>li>ul li:hover>a {
opacity: 1;
}
```

to no avail.

The theme's original CSS pertaining to the top navbar menu is:

```
#header .top-header .header-logo {
    display: block;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#header .top-header .header-logo:hover,
#header .top-header .header-logo:focus {
    color: #f1d204;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation {
    float: right;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation > ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li {
    margin-left: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Lato";
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children a {
    padding-right: 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children a:after {
    content: "\f107";
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
    width: 200px;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);

    transform: translateX(-50%);

}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -3px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu:before {
    display: none;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #8c9597;
    text-transform: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Lato";
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:hover > a,
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:focus-within > a {
    color: #f1d204;
    border-left: 3px solid #f1d204;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li a:after {
    display: none;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li:hover a,
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li:focus-within a {
    color: #ffde00;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to link the site?

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And, please try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there have some error, and which part of CSS not working? Besides, from the Illdy forum, I found a [same issue](https://colorlib.com/wp/forums/topic/ie-and-edge-not-showing-dropdown-hover-menus/), might be it's the question you posted, I think you'd better to confirm with IIIdy developer whether this theme support IE and Edge browser..

Answer (score 0):

Add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>` between the head tags. I personally used this and I had no problems with either IE or Edge. You should also check the syntax which could be read differently and wrong.